# Centering a horizontal menu with sub-menus

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, submenu

I found a simple horizontal css menu that I though would be easy to manipulate.

[Menu sample](http://www.cssterm.com/css-menus/horizontal-css-menu/simple-drop-down-menu)

The way the current css is written, the menu is left justified. I want the ul centered within the div while keeping the li's left justified. I've spent hours trying to figure this out and I've reviewed similar posts on this site. I'm hoping there is a simple fix. Thanks for your help.

Here is my html:

```
<div id="horizontal_menu">
    <ul class="drop_menu">
    <li><a href="#" title="home" class="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="surnames" class="">Surnames</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="vital records" class="">Vital Records</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" title="Birth" class="">Birth</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Marriage" class="">Marriage</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Divorce" class="">Divorce</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Death" class="">Death</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Obiturary" class="">Obiturary</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Land" class="">Land</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Church" class="">Church</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Military" class="">Military</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Adoptions" class="">Adoptions</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Education" class="">Education</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Medical" class="">Medical</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Newspapers" class="" >Newspapers</a></li>
        </ul></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="Photo Album" class="">Album</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="Relatives" class="">Relatives</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" title="Ancestors" >Ancestors</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Descendants" >Descendants</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Memorial" >Memorial</a></li>
        </ul></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="Sources" class="">Sources</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="Timeline" class="">Timeline</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="Index" class="">Index</a></li>

    </ul>

 </div>
```

Here is my version of the CSS:

```
#horizontal_menu{
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #E0162B;
    }
.drop_menu {
    width:1024px;
    background:#E0162B;
    padding:0;
    margin: 0 auto;

    list-style-type:none;
    height:30px;
}

.drop_menu ul{
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
    }
.drop_menu li { 
    float:left;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;      
}
.drop_menu li a {
    padding:6px 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    font:14px 'Marcellus SC', serif;
}

/* Submenu */
.drop_menu ul {
    position:absolute;
    left:-9999px;
    top:-9999px;
    list-style-type:none;
}
.drop_menu li:hover { position:relative; background:#0052A5; }
.drop_menu li:hover ul {
    left:0px;
    top:30px;
    background:##0052A5;
    padding:0px;
}

.drop_menu li:hover ul li a {
    padding:5px;
    display: inline-block;
    width:168px;
    text-indent:15px;
    background-color:#0052A5;
}
.drop_menu li:hover ul li a:hover { background:#E0162B; }
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of simple tweaks to the CSS allows for that:

```
.drop_menu {
    background:#005555;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    list-style-type:none;
    height:30px;
    text-align: center;
}
.drop_menu > li { display: inline-block; }
.drop_menu li a {
    padding:9px 20px;
    display:block;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    font:12px arial, verdana, sans-serif;
}

/* Submenu */
.drop_menu ul {
    position:absolute;
    left:-9999px;
    top:-9999px;
    list-style-type:none;
    text-align: left;
}
.drop_menu li:hover { position:relative; background:#5FD367; }
.drop_menu li:hover ul {
    left:0px;
    top:30px;
    background:#5FD367;
    padding:0px;
}

.drop_menu li:hover ul li a {
    padding:5px;
    display:block;
    width:168px;
    text-indent:15px;
    background-color:#5FD367;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would use this for left justifying the `li`s

```
.drop_menu li a {
    padding: 6px 20px 6px 6px;
}
```

And it's kind of a hack but works perfectly. Try this for centering the `ul` to the `#horizontal_menu` div

```
.drop_menu{
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    left: 50%;
    position: relative;
}
```

**EDIT**:
I have seen you have a bit complicated structure than I thought.
Check [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/aniskhan001/78rPz/). It's working perfectly. You can use this CSS.

Answer (score 0):

`text-align: center;`

Here's the code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zomcn

I suggest you clean your CSS and it's not bad to use `class` so you can easily target the correct element in your stylesheet. I removed some of the code as it is irrelevant to what you want to accomplish.